# code coverage with Heroku CI

Tags: code-coverage, codecov, heroku-ci

We are in the process of privatising our repo and have moved our CI to use Heroku's service. We are now trying to work out how to get code coverage reports so that we don't merge with reduced coverage. I am trying to work out how to generate such reports, as previously travis handled this for us in conjunction with codecov.

[Code cov](https://docs.codecov.io/reference#upload) docs say Heroku CI is not one of their supported CI services. And I've not found any information for CodeCov support for Heroku CI. Does anyone know if there is a free code coverage tool supported by Heroku?

Comment: did you end up with a solution for python + Heroku CI?